# xcode 5 crashes while opening xib developed in xcode6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, xcode5, xib

I want to test my app for ios6. So, i downloaded xcode 5. In xcode5 While opening xib, xcode crashes with following log. Kindly suggest a solution.

```
Process:               Xcode [2807]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               5.0 (3332.25)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-3332025000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2807]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-07-14 12:55:38.017 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F20A6FAB-50EF-797B-17ED-DCA402DAE3BA


Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:36
Details:  Failed to launch cocoa touch tool: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fa34bda8380 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa34b78c2f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (2879) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 6.}
Object:   <NSThread: 0x7fa341c2bb30>
Method:   -cocoaTouchToolForTargetRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa341c2bb30>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
```

Comment: You don't need to use Xcode 5 just to test your app on iOS 6. You can't distribute to the AppStore without compiling against the iOS 8 SDK so you need to use Xcode 6 to compile it anyway. Just plug an iOS 6 device into Xcode or download legacy simulators from Xcode preferences. Maybe you should also ask yourself if you really need to support iOS 6 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In the File Inspector of the XIB file, there's a "Interface Builder Document" popup and one of choices is "Opens in".  And from there you can select "Xcode 5".

If you have auto-layout turned on, then the lowest you can go is Xcode 5.1.

[image: Change compatible Xcode version for XIB files]

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunately this solution did not worked for me.

Comment: will not turning off auto layouts effect my views?

Comment: It certainly will :-) but if you want to run your app in Xcode 5.0, that's the only way you are going to get your xib to not crash the IDE.